# ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for '{{node ReadFile}} = ReadFile[](ReadFile/filename)' with input shapes: [10222]

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I'm writing a Machine Learning but i got a error
Code:

```
    import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import imread
import pickle
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

print("TF version: ",tf.__version__)
print("GPU ", tf.config.list_physical_devices("GPU"))
label = pd.read_csv("drive/MyDrive/Destinathion Data/labels.csv")
print(label)
a = label['breed']
print(a)
filename = ["drive/MyDrive/Destinathion Data/train/"+fname+".jpg" for fname in label['id']]
print(filename)
uni = np.unique(label['breed'])
boolen = [labela == uni for labela in a]
len(boolen)
x = filename
y = boolen
limited = 100
Xh, Xv, Yh, Yv = train_test_split(x[0:limited],y[0:limited],test_size=0.2)

size = 224
def GPU_Pre(fileName):
  im = tf.io.read_file(filename)
  im = tf.image.decode_jpeg(im,channels=3)
  im = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(im,tf.float32)
  im = tf.image.resize(im,size = [size,size])
  return im

def Label(path,label):
  ims = GPU_Pre(path)
  return ims,label

def ba(x,y=None, s = 32,va = False,te = False):
  if te:
    data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(x)))
    ba = data.map(GPU_Pre).batch(s)
    return ba
  elif va:
    data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(x),tf.constant(y)))
    ba = data.map(Label)
    return ba.batch(s)
  else:
    data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((tf.constant(x),tf.constant(y)))
    data = data.shuffle(buffer_size=len(x))
    datab = data.map(Label)
    return datab.batch(s)

tr = ba(Xh,Yh)
val = ba(x = Xv,y = Yv,va=True)
```

Error:

> > ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)  in <cell line: 52>()
> > 50     return datab.batch(s)
> > 51
> > ---> 52 tr = ba(Xh,Yh)
> > 53 val = ba(x = Xv,y = Yv,va=True)
>
> 28 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py
> in _create_c_op(graph, node_def, inputs, control_inputs, op_def,
> extract_traceback)    1971   except errors.InvalidArgumentError as e:
> 1972     # Convert to ValueError for backwards compatibility.
> -> 1973     raise ValueError(e.message)    1974     1975   # Record the current Python stack trace as the creating stacktrace of this
>
> ValueError: in user code:
>
> ```
> File "<ipython-input-10-ffb817acd216>", line 34, in Label  *
>     ims = GPU_Pre(path)
> File "<ipython-input-7-0336c8fcf47c>", line 27, in GPU_Pre  *
>     im = tf.io.read_file(filename)
>
> ValueError: Shape must be rank 0 but is rank 1 for '{{node ReadFile}} = ReadFile[](ReadFile/filename)' with input shapes:
> ```
>
> [10222].

Can you help me